# How to assign a different id for every element

Tags: javascript

I have got two list, one contains text for span elements, that I assign using this forEach loop:

```
spans.forEach(function(el) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = el;
  list.appendChild(span);
})
```

How would I assign an id to every span in the list using another list?
Both lists contains the same amount of elements and the id[0] should be assign to text[0] and so on.

Comment: use a `for` loop

Comment: `span.id = ...`, use the second parameter of the `.forEach()` callback for the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by using the second parameter of `forEach`, like so:

```js
let spans = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let list = document.getElementById("list");

spans.forEach(function(el, i) {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = el;
  span.id = spans[i];
  list.appendChild(span);
});

for (let child of list.childNodes) {
  console.log(child);
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your seconds list is named as `ids`

```
spans.forEach(function(el,index) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = el;
  span.id=ids[index];
  list.appendChild(span);    
})
```